# APK release not update installed AAB app from Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, apk

I have installed previous version of my app from Google Play Store.
Now, I make an apk release with the same keystore file with `gradlew assembleRelease` command or with android studio, and try to install it manually in device or with `gradlew installRelease` on emulator.
But every time I got **App not installed** error.

I got this on LOGCAT:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.myapp.myapp signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!
```

I use `enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture` in my gradle file.
and also I enable v2 signing with these commands in gradle file (in release section of signingConfigs):

```
signingConfigs {
  debug {
    storeFile file(...)
    storePassword ...
    keyAlias ...
    keyPassword ...
  }
  release {
    storeFile file(...)
    storePassword ...
    keyAlias ...
    keyPassword ...
    v1SigningEnabled true
    v2SigningEnabled true
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Also if I install the previous version of my app manually, the Play Store won't update it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour.

This is because the keystore signatures don't match, as most likely you have opted in for your signing key to be managed by Google. You will have to uninstall the previous app before installing the new version if it comes from a different source (Google Play/ Android Studio build).

Comment: I got it. But I want to upload the apk to my website and users can download and update app from website. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: In other word, how can I opt-out from play signing key?